# Empty parameter when passing through header location

Tags: php

I'm setting a variable based on an array. When I echo the variable it displays on the screen, however when I try to add it to a Header Location it doesn't show up in the URL of the next page - everything else does:

```
$myid = $selected_cat3[0]['id'];

Header("Location:/cat-dashboard/cat-results/?catID=" . $myid
     . "&question1=" . $_GET['question1'] . "&question2=" . $_GET['question2']
     . "&question3=" . $_GET['question3'] . "&question4=" . $_GET['question4']
     . "&question5=" . $_GET['question5'] . "&question6=" . $_GET['question6']
     . "&question7=" . $_GET['question7'] . "&question8=" . $_GET['question8']);
```

This is the generated url:

```
/cat-dashboard/cat-results/?catID=&question1=0&question2=3&q‌​uestion3=1&question4‌​=1&question5=1&quest‌​ion6=2&question7=1&q‌​uestion8=3
```

Am I doing something wrong? It doesn't show even if I use: `$myid = "1";`

Comment: It's /cat-dashboard/cat-results/?catID=&question1=0&question2=3&question3=1&question4=1&question5=1&question6=2&question7=1&question8=3

Comment: 1. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php 2. You might need a space after the semicolon and before the URL. E.G `header('Location: https://some_url')`

Comment: It looks like these variables are being set in a form, why not set the form action to the url you want instead of redirecting in the header?

Comment: How are you verifying that `$myid` has a values?

Comment: What's the content of `$selected_cat3`?

Comment: @PatrickQ I can echo the contents to the page.

Comment: What happens if you echo your full URL string (everything inside the `header()` function? Quite frankly, I think you're leaving something out here.  Is there more code that you're not showing?